Vercel shutdown application
I am writing a small Telegram bot and deploying it on Vercel. I have registered all the webhooks. The code below handles all the messages at the beginning of the launch, but after 10 seconds, it no longer responds to the webhook. What could be the problem?
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const token = '____';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;
  const messageText = msg.text;

  if (messageText === '/start') {
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Hi');
  } else {
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Your message: ' + messageText);
  }
});

bot.on('polling_error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});

bot.on('polling', () => {
  console.log('Ruuned...');
});

app.post('/api/webhook', (req, res) => {
  console.log('wake up');
  res.status(200).send('wake up ended');
});



Vercel is a Serverless Platform. Your application, on the other hand, expects a server that "always stay on". Unless your TelegramBot can respond "on demand" without listening, it will not work.
Read more on https://vercel.com/docs/functions
